# im trying to make a .vbs file so it can sendkeys

Tags: vbscript

So im trying to make a .VBS file so it sendskeys but the problem is that theres a error! please look for mistakes and say the correct code

```
set wShell = createObject("wscript.shell")
wShell.sendKeys ":){ENTER}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use `"{(}"` for `"("` and `"{)}"` for `")"`

So =

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Bracket=")"
WshShell.SendKeys ":"
WshShell.SendKeys "{"&Bracket&"}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```